# Calculating Molar Volume from crystal volume

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, metal

I am trying to calculate molar volume of certain crystal lattices to be used for crystal growth kinetics calculations. The information I have is the crystal volume & crystal lattices. For example the crystal $\ce{Cu41Sn11}$ has the structure cF416 and the information taken from a certain crystal database is as follows:

Atom Formula: Cu<sub>41.5</sub>Sn<sub>10.5</sub>

Cell volume:    5.81258 nm<sup>3</sup>

Cell density (calculated):  8.85 Mg m<sup>-3</sup>

Now I have tried 2 approaches to it.

1. First was the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_volume#Crystalline_solids) formula for molar volumes

V<sub>m</sub>= N<sub>A</sub>V<sub>cell</sub> / Z

molar volume = (Avorgados number x crystal cell volume) / number of formula units in a crystal

This gives the following output for the above mentioned crystal

Molar Volume = 6.022 x 10<sup>23</sup> x 5.81258 x 10 <sup>-27</sup> / 51

Molar volume = 6.731 x 10 <sup>-5</sup>

2. The second one is i figured out the formula

Molar volume = Molar Mass of crystal / Cell Density

So in this case:

Molar mass of crystal $\ce{Cu41Sn11}$ = 41 x 63.546 + 11 x 118.71 = 3911.2 gms (3.9112 Kg)

Molar Volume = 3.9112 / 8850 = 4.41944 x 10 <sup>-4</sup>

These two approaches yield two different results, so i wanted to make sure where am i making the mistake?

In case you're interested in the crystal database, here it is:

[image: Database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well figured out the answer, I had to take the correct value of Z from the database. The difference in values was because of the incorrect value of Z (which was actually 8) . When you use Z =8 , the two solution yield 'approximately' equal results.